# Promise all not firing

Tags: javascript, express, promise

I'm trying to get promises work for the first time. However, my `Promise.all` is never firing.

I'm using node.js & express

```
const promises = [
    new Promise( () => {
        var query = `...`;  

        mssql.query(query, function(obj){
            finalRes['key1'] = obj.recordset;
            return true;
            //this works
        });
    }),
    new Promise( () => {
        var query = `...`;  

        mssql.query(query, function(obj){
            finalRes['key2'] = obj.recordset;
            return true;
            //this works
        });
    }),
    ...
]

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    res.send(finalRes);
    // this is never firing
});
```

I have been googling stuff and I can't find a solution. I would appreciate someone point out what I do wrong here.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promise creation code is wrong, as they never resolve. What you actually should do is fire `resolve` functions inside your callback-based code. I'd go a bit further - and make all those promises resolve with their results instead of modifying some external value. Like this:

```
const promises = [
  new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    var query = `...`;  
    mssql.query(query, function(obj){
      resolve({key1:obj.recordset});
    });
  }),
  new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    var query = `...`;  
    mssql.query(query, function(obj){
      resolve({key2:obj.recordset});
    });
  }) // ...
];

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  res.send(Object.assign({}, ...results));
});
```

Depending on how queries are built, you might go even further - and write a generic query-generator function, which takes query and key as params, and returns a promise. Again, this function should be easy to test.

As a sidenote, your code is overly optimistic, it should also provide `error` callbacks with `reject()` invoke to each query.

Comment: I just tried that but I get error `>resolve(); ReferenceError: resolve is not defined` ... any idea why?

Comment: Because you missed that `(resolve, reject)` part in Promise constructor?